# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called in subclassed UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, subclass

I have subclassed `UITableView` so that I can detect when 3D Touch gestures are performed from anywhere on the view. This works great, however `didSelectRowForIndexPath` is now never called.

Here is my subclass:

```
protocol PassTouchesTableViewDelegate {
    func touchMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>)
    func touchEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>)
}

class PassTouchesTableView: UITableView {
    var delegatePass: PassTouchesTableViewDelegate?

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.delegatePass?.touchMoved(touches)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.delegatePass?.touchEnded(touches)
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can get `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` working again?

Comment: Call the superclass implementation of the methods you override

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Seems obvious now.